# longpoll api vk php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Прочитал документацию вк, и ни чего не понял.

Так же не понятно: для чего в скрипте использовать `while`.
Вроде же.
Как я понял

1. запрос getLongPollServer
2. получаем ответ
3. обрабатываем

Если закончилось время. То создаем новый запрос `getLongPoll`.
Если событие: делаем что нужно.
И отправляем запрос вк на сервер который получили в запросе `getLongPollServer`. И + в запросе добавляем ts

Зачем вообще `while`?
Если мы делаем запрос в вк.
И вк присылает ответ.
Получается: что вк заходит на сайт и присылает `json`.
Точно так же как и в `callback`.

Подскажите пожалуйста.
А лучше приложите пример.

Я нормально знаю php.
Но плохо знаю longpoll.
Callback средне

Comment: Скачайте себе в браузер расширение под названием `Language tool`. В вашем вопросе слов 10 с ошибками было)

Comment: Спасибо, за исправление ощибок. Писал просто быстро и не перечитывал после написания

Comment: Как можно нормально знать `php` но `callback` знать средне? :\

Comment: Ошибочка вышла. callback знаю хорошо, и php тоже ( по крайне мере: я знаю больше чем стандарт у юлогиров на ut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае с `Callback` сам ВК отправляет запросы на сайт для обработки. `LongPoll` работает в обратную сторону: приложение отправляет запрос к вк, чтобы получить список произошедших событий
`while` нужен для того, чтобы отправить следующий длинный запрос (а также изменить временную метку, начиная с которой нужно получить произошедшие события, то самое поле `ts`), а не завершить работу программы

Comment: То есть я должен буду каждую мили секунду делать запрос на сайт который вывел вк в getLongPollServer?

Comment: @СлаваНосков, нет. Запрос нужно делать тогда, когда предыдущий завершился. В ответе будет `ts`, который нужно указать в запросе
В документации описано, в каких ситуациях нужно заново получить сервер

Comment: А как понять как раз токи что запрос завершился?

Comment: Бот должен переходить на сайт, и застывать до тех пор пока вк не даёт ответ? Если так: как предугадать время когда будет событие

Comment: По сути так.... file_get_contents(); это запрос на сайт который мы получили при file_get_contents(‘https://api.vk.com/method/getLongPollServer?’); а далее входим в while while(true) {...} и делаем запрос file_gef_contents(); и sleep(30);??

Comment: Как я знаю просто: файл php он не может приостановить работу. ( кроме sleep() ), а это значит что каждую мили секунду он будет повторять цикл и повторять

Comment: Не нужно ничего угадывать. После выполнения `file_get_contents` будет получен ответ от ВК, в котором будет массив с событиями, которые и нужно будет обрабатывать. Да, он будет отправлять очень много запросов. В этом и задумка longpoll, что отправляется много запросов, а в ответ приходит массив событий

Comment: Это будет при каждом запросе?

Comment: sleep делать не нужно. Просто отправить запрос и обработать ответ

Comment: То есть при while(true){file_get_contents(‘[ссылка]’);}

Comment: Это будет каждую секунду происходить так как запрос находится в while

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104552/discussion-between---and-alexbrin).